# code to run magnifier vb

Tags: vb.net

`this is the code I have System . Diagnostics . Process . Start(("magnify"))`

I want to Make a button in vb which loads the magnifier.

but with the code above ,instead  it just calls up the settings.
I have looked up all the c m d hacks on YouTube , found nothing for loading system magnifier from visual basic, mostly what I have found for magnifier , was how to create a magnifier ,

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply just need to open the process from the System32 folder.

Here's how you can open the magnifier:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MagnifyPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "Magnify.exe")
    Process.Start(MagnifyPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Barry Carroll Also a note for the future: When asking questions on Stackoverflow, be sure not to write too much unuseful information and not too many dots and commas. It is not very appreciated by the users. I'm not saying this to be mean, I only say it because you're more likely to get help with good and concise questions.